# XSane - Ubuntu 20.04 - Epson L365 Scanner

Tags: 20.04, epson, xsane

Trying to make my Epson L 365 Scanner work with XSane, and its not working. Tells me it didn find any device. Checked connections, the printer is working, but not the scanner.

Tried to install epson driver, but there is only version for 18.04 and 19.10. None of them worked.

If someone could give me some advice. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1237279/edit) and provide more information. Have you installed the Epson scanner driver for Linux? See https://epson.com/Support/wa00821#

Comment: I also recommend the Sane ppa. https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-release

Comment: Have you tried [their software](http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/epsonscan2_e.html), Epson Scan 2? That's the only way I could make my Epson scanner works.